# D3 JavaScript return data value plus variable from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 function where I want to return a specific data element based on a user selection.

For instance:

```
var selected = this.value;

line.y(function(d) { return d.selected; });
```

The `selected` variable will be a placeholder for the real element name.

The above code block doesn't work, but I'm wondering if some other construct would work.  I've tried several other combinations without luck including `return d. + selected`.

The alternative that does work would be a case statement or many if/else statements such as:

```
if(selected === "element1") {
    return d.element1;
}
else {
    return d.element2;
}
```

I'd rather avoid this though since there are many different options.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
line.y(function(d) { return d[selected]; });
```

This has nothing to do with D3, it's JavaScript syntax:

```
d.element1
d['element1']

var key = 'element1';
d[key]
```

all access the same property.